# Optional regex replacement between Oracle SQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, replace, expression

I want to build a SQL-Parser which turns Oracle SQL into Postgresql. My problem is the Replacement of the regex with optional values.
(Info: In the Sequence you don't need to fill out all options, sometimes there are 5, sometimes 2.)

```
    Searchregex for the sequence:
    CREATE\s+SEQUENCE\s+(["a-zA-Z0-9_$.]+)
    (\s+INCREMENT\s+([0-9]+)|())?
    (\s+MINVALUE\s+([0-9]+)|())?
    (\s+MAXVALUE\s+([0-9]+)|())?
    (\s+START\s+([0-9]+)|())?
    (\s+CACHE\s+([0-9]+)|())?
    (\s+CYCLE\s+|\s+NOCYCLE\s+|())?
```

My Problem is the replacement with optional values.

For example:

```
//PostgreSQL
CREATE SEQUENCE sq1 
INCREMENT 1 
START 2;

CREATE SEQUENCE sq2 
INCREMENT 1 
MAXVALUE 5 
START 2;
```

These two sequences are written in PostgreSQL. The difference between PostgreSQL and Oracle SQL is simple, there are just two words. The Oracle SQL statement has to look like the following:

```
//Oracle SQL
CREATE SEQUENCE sq1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
START 2;

CREATE SEQUENCE sq2 
INCREMENT BY 1 
MAXVALUE 5 
START WITH 2;
```

Following the part of the JSON-file:

```
//JSON
{
        "name": "SEQUENCE",
        "alias": "SEQUENCE",
        "from": "CREATE \\s+SEQUENCE\\s+([\"a-zA-Z0-9_$.]+)
                 (\\s+INCREMENT\\s+([0-9]+)|())?
                 (\\s+MINVALUE\\s+([0-9]+)|())?
                 (\\s+MAXVALUE\\s+([0-9]+)|())?
                 (\\s+START\\s+([0-9]+)|())?
                 (\\s+CACHE\\s+([0-9]+)|())?
                 (\\s+CYCLE\\s+|\\s+NOCYCLE\\s+|())?"
        "to":  "CREATE\\s+SEQUENCE\\s+
                INCREMENT\\s+$3\\s+
                MINVALUE\\s+$6\\s+
                MAXVALUE\\s+$9\\s+
                START\\s+$12\\s+
                CACHE\\s+$15\\s+
                (CYCLE|NOCYCLE)"       
    }
```

The problem is, that i don't know the right regex for the "to" statement. This JSON-File ist like the rule for replacement for my program. If i do it like this, it works sometimes, but also had many mistakes when there isn't a value (Like maxvalue or sth.)
How can i make one single regex to replace any sequence i want?

Comment: But how do i get the Values? This is just the search regex, in my JSON-file it is the part "from". When i want to replace it, i need also another regex with the values of the groups

Comment: Could you provide a sample output, and a snippet from the JSON-file you are talking about?

Comment: Edited it. So i hope you can help me now :)